# Add two timestamp variable in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have written my trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_total_duration` AFTER UPDATE ON `sales_activity`
 FOR EACH ROW thisTrigger:BEGIN  
IF(NEW.activity_id=4) 
    THEN LEAVE thisTrigger;
ELSEIF NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM sales_duration_update WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND   date = CURDATE()) 
    THEN INSERT INTO sales_duration_update (user_id,date,total_duration) VALUES (NEW.user_id,CURDATE(),NEW.duration);
ELSE
    //problem is here when total_duration = total_duration + NEW.duration
    UPDATE sales_duration_update SET total_duration = total_duration + NEW.duration WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND date = CURDATE();
END IF;
```

END

Problem is here in code 
`total_duration = total_duration + NEW.duration`
where both variable are `timestamp` variable.How can I add two `timestamp` variables in trigger?

Comment: You can show some examples and some test data. [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) and [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) functions can be useful.

Comment: I tried total_duration = TIMESTAMPADD(total_duration + NEW.duration) but its didn't work

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.May be will help someone.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_total_duration` AFTER UPDATE ON `sales_activity`
FOR EACH ROW thisTrigger:BEGIN  
IF(NEW.activity_id=4) 
THEN LEAVE thisTrigger;
ELSEIF NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM sales_duration_update WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND   date     = CURDATE()) 
    THEN 
INSERT INTO sales_duration_update (user_id,date,total_duration) VALUES     (NEW.user_id,CURDATE(),NEW.duration);
ELSE
UPDATE sales_duration_update SET total_duration = ADDTIME(total_duration,     NEW.duration) WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND date = CURDATE();
END IF;
```